# How can I convert char* to double*?

Tags: c++, casting

I have a function that has to convert a char pointer to a double pointer. Originally the code was written as `(double *)data`, where data is the char*, but this caused a warning with cppcheck as an "incompatible binary data representation" and, from what I have read, is not generally recommended in c++ since it is more of a c-style method.

I have tried `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`, but none have worked properly. `atof` can convert to a double, but I cannot use this with a double* - `double *vd = &atof(data)` - because it complains `lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`.

Here is an example of what I am working with:

```
exStateData convertToStateData(char* data, int size) {
    ...
    unsigned int vd_size = *((unsigned int*) data);
    data += sizeof(unsigned int);
    ...
    double *vd = (double*)data;
    return exStateData(vd, vd + vd_size);
}
```

How can I cast a char* to a double*?

Comment: It's really not at all clear what you're trying to do and why. Could you give us enough code to understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you make and show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Note: an MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.

Comment: Also, even if you could take the address of the return value of `atof`, it would do you no good. That value ceases to exist as soon as that statement completes, so you'd have the former address of a now non-existent temporary. (That you would try it suggests that some misunderstandings might be behind your question, but we can't tell if or which.)

Comment: I'mworking on adding an example, it'll be put in properly in a few minutes

Comment: Your code really doesn't make much sense. How do you know that `data` (after you incremented it) is properly aligned to read a `double` from it? You're trying to do platform-specific things that are never going to be safe. (What if an `int` is four bytes and a `double` is eight? You could be attempting to dereference a pointer that can't possibly point to a double because it's not aligned on an eight byte boundary.)

Comment: Yeah that example isn't very helpful. You need to explain what `data` and `size` represents and what the first parameter of `exStateData`'s constructor is supposed to be.

Comment: `(double *)data` is correct code, using a different cast wont' solve the problem your warning is talking about. The problem is due to (potentially) accessing character data as `double`

Answer (score 1):

The strict aliasing rules in `C++` mean you can not safely cast a pointer to just any type. The only types that can legally alias other types are `char`, `unsigned char` and `std::byte` (C++17).

For that reason you need to **copy** the data from your `char*` source into a correctly aligned `double` (or whatever other type).

For example:

```
double get_from_char_array(char const* buffer)
{
    // correctly aligned double
    double d;

    // get the address of the double and convert it
    // to a char pointer because char pointer can alias
    // any other type
    char* dp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d);

    // copy the data out of the buffer into the
    // memory occupied by the double d
    std::copy(buffer, buffer + sizeof(double), dp);

    return d;
}
```

Please note that the binary representation of `double` is not specified by the standard and so converting a `double` in this way is not necessarily portable between platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The safe way to do it, is to use memcpy:

```
exStateData convertToStateData(char* data, int size) {
    ...
    unsigned int vd_size;
    memcpy( &vd_size, data, sizeof(vd_size));
    data += sizeof(vd_size);
    ...
    std::vector<double> vd(vd_size);
    memcpy(&vd[0], data, vd_size*sizeof(double));
    return exStateData(&vd[0], &vd[0] + vd_size); 
}
```

The problem is that this involves a lot of copying.  The problem though is that `data` is probably not suitably aligned for a double.

(Once you do this, you might want to change the overload of `exStateData` which you call on the last line, to take a reference to the vector - it makes the call much cleaner).